# Как подключить библиотеку которая лежит на gitlab?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-library

Есть написаная мной библиотека, она лежит на gitlab. И есть мой основной проект, как подключить эту библиотеку к проекту?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще варианты:

3. Публикуете в локальном Maven с помощью плагина: https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin
   Самый простой вариант если работаете один.
4. Поднимаете свой собственный Maven repo с помощью Nexus: https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype
   Публикуйте потом в нем что душе угодно, будет доступно всем, кому доступен адрес репозитория.

В обоих случаях после публикации прописываете репозиторий в проект и библиотеку как обычную зависимость.

Answer (score 3):

Варианты:

1. Клонируете библиотеку на Вашу машину. Импортируете ее в качестве модуля в проект через Android Studio (в градле все пропишется само).
2. Если хотите динамически подключать через удаленный репозиторий, то необходимо опубликовать библиотеку, как описано здесь:

> https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-and-publishing-an-android-library--cms-24582

А затем просто прописываете зависимость, указав `compile 'group:artifact:version'`.

Comment: А можно подключать через удаленный репозитарий без публикации библиотеки?

Comment: А как Вы подтянете библиотеку из удаленного репозитория, не регистрируя там библиотеку? Здесь имеется в виду репозиторий не гитлаба, а например mavenCentral, jcenter, bintray и др.